# Cycles render low on quality vs Evee

Tags: cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine

i am just a week into blender. I made a donut but the render result using Evee is what i intended and it looks better detailed than cycles engine render (shouldn't it be other way round?)
Details like texture, light wrap around the edges, outer rim in the center are missimg when i switch to Cycles engine

Am i missing some setting for cycles or is it how cycles is supposed to render?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi :). Sometimes Eevee might look as good/better than Cycles. Eevee's shadows/SSS/reflections are limited, so it's easier to not overdo it. Cycles excels in contact shadows, indirect light, but might be harder to fine tune :))

Comment: TLDR; probably overdone SSS, share the file to get relevant answers :))

Comment: @JachymMichal - i have attached the blend file for users perusal here just now